# Serial Inputs into Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a project that I'm working on that takes some analog inputs from an Arduino Mega and sends it over to a Raspberry Pi. I am using Kivy as a GUI development tool and have things working pretty well. The main issue that I'm having is getting the analog inputs to update on Kivy. I'm following this https://www.instructables.com/id/Sending-Temperature-Humidity-Data-From-Arduino-to-/ code(the py code is at the bottom). In my program, the while true loop get stuck in the loop(duh), and won't move onto the rest of the program. However, if I take out the while loop, the analog inputs will be displayed, but they won't be updated.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to call the function periodically, so that my program will continue past the while loop? The code is quite extensive and I didn't want to bog down the screen with it.

Thank you for any assistance/ideas! I'm quite stuck

Comment: Put your while loop in a separate thread and do the kivy updates using `Clock.schedule_once` to get that bit of code to run back on the main thread,

Comment: most GUIs has some method/class to run function periodicaly. `PyQT` has `QTimer`, `tkinter` has `.after()`. You should check `Kivy` documentation for this kind method/class

Comment: using Google "kivy timer" I found [kivy.Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

Comment: Using kivy.Clock did that trick! Thanks guys!